# www Error determining IP Addresses

Tags: azure, dns, cloud, azure-virtual-network, no-www

I have deployed a VM on Azure and assign the Reserve IP address like **52.168.xxx.xxx** to a host like **xxx.xxxx.com**

Now when i try to check the IP Address for my host name like this(**without www.**) --

**xxx.xxxx.com**

It returns me the right IP Address

But when i try to IP Address for my url like this --

```
**www.xxx.xxxx.com**
```

It returns me an error ---

> Error determining IP Addresses for www.xxx.xxxx.com

So my question how just putting a www. in-front of a url can return this error !

Anyone have any idea of this issue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your Question, You've binded the IP address to your website xxx.xxxx.com.

**Solution:**
You need to bind your IP address to both the host name xxx.xxxx.com as well as www.xxx.xxxx.com

Or point a CNAME record to the initial A record: `www.example.com`. IN CNAME `example.com`

Comment: Or point a CNAME record to the initial A record: `www.example.com.  IN  CNAME  example.com`